# Setting to zero non defined array variables

Tags: symbolic, symbols, built-in-symbols

I have a situation like this (for example):

```
vv[1, 2, 3] = a;
vv[1, 3, 2] = 11;
vv[3, 1, 2] = 7;
vv[2, 1, 3] = 5;

Sum[LeviCivitaTensor[3][[mu, nu, eta]]*vv[mu, nu, eta], {mu, 1, 
  3}, {nu, 1, 3}, {eta, 1, 3}]
```

I obtain this:

```
   -9 + a + vv[2, 3, 1] - vv[3, 2, 1]
```

I have not defined `vv[2, 3, 1]` and `vv[3, 2, 1]`so they appear as symbolic expressions, there is another symbolic expr which is `vv[1, 2, 3] = a`.
Now here is the question.
**Is there a way to set to zero all the components not defined** like these ones, if yes **does it discriminate** the variable `a` and `vv[3, 2, 1]`  ?

Thank you.

Comment: Something like `vv[__] = 0`?

Comment: `Sum[LeviCivitaTensor[3][[mu, nu, eta]]*vv[mu, nu, eta], {mu, 1, 
   3}, {nu, 1, 3}, {eta, 1, 3}] /. _vv :> 0`

Comment: @BobHanlon please could you tell me why using your sintax the code works even if some parts of array are not defined?

Comment: @siderius - any undefined terms have the form `vv[mu, nu, eta]`,  that is, an expression with the `Head` of `vv`. The rule `_vv :> 0` replaces any expression with `Head` of `vv` with `0`.

Comment: @BobHanlon and correctly it discriminates `a`. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use a SparseArray (which sets all non-defined elements to zero by default):

```
vv = SparseArray[{{1, 2, 3} -> a, {1, 3, 2} -> 11, 
                  {3, 1, 2} -> 7, {2, 1, 3} -> 5}];
Sum[LeviCivitaTensor[3][[mu, nu, eta]]*vv[[mu, nu, eta]], 
                  {mu, 1, 3}, {nu, 1, 3}, {eta, 1, 3}]
-9 + a
```